# My map data's are not getting stored in the mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

hey i am facing a problem of data not getting stored in the table which i created in mysql database. i have created 4 tables trip,Droute,Wroute,Troute
previously when i had only two tables trip and route my data were getting properly populated in the table but now as i want my data to be segregated as per travel modes so,now i am facing this problem.here's my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var source, destination;
            var routeArr = [];
            var routeArr2 = [];
            var routeArr3 = [];
            var directionsDisplay;                                                      // The whole map rendering or displaying.
            var globalResponse;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();                // For Availing the Direction Services provided by APIs

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {              //  This acts as a pageload Function
                new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
                new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({'draggable': true});
            });

            function GetRoute() {
                var kolkata = new google.maps.LatLng(22.7383075, 88.454424);  // Center of the Map (lat and long of kolkata)
                var mapOptions = {                                           // Setting the View of the Map
                    zoom: 7,
                    center: kolkata
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);   // Variable for map view

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);                                              // Map view

                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));             //Panel View

                source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
                destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

                var request =                        // variable request 1
                {                                   // DirectionsService
                    origin: source,
                    destination: destination,
                    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING            // here driving is selected
                };

                var request2 =                        // variable request 2
                {                                   // DirectionsService
                    origin: source,
                    destination: destination,
                    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING            // here WALKING is selected
                };


                var request3 =                        // variable request 3
                {                                   // DirectionsService
                    origin: source,
                    destination: destination,
                    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT            // here TRANSIT is selected
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {   // RouteService
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        globalResponse = response;
                        routeArr = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < globalResponse.routes.length; i++) {

                            routeArr.push([globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text, globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text]);
                        }
                        var s = 'Possible routes are: <br />';
                        for (i = 0; i < routeArr.length; ++i) {

                            routeArr[i][0] = routeArr[i][0].trim();
                            routeArr[i][0] = routeArr[i][0].substring(0, routeArr[i][0].length - 3)
                            routeArr[i][1] = routeArr[i][1].split(' ');
                            if (routeArr[i][1].length == 2 && routeArr[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'm') {
                                routeArr[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr[i][1][0]);
                            }
                            else if (routeArr[i][1].length == 4 && routeArr[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'h') {
                                routeArr[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr[i][1][0]) * 60 + parseInt(routeArr[i][1][2]);
                            }
                            else {
                                routeArr[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr[i][1][0]) * 24 * 60 + parseInt(routeArr[i][1][2] * 60);   //for day hour minutes,all calculation under mins
                            }
                            s += "Distance: " + routeArr[i][0] + ", " + "Duration: " + routeArr[i][1] + "<br />";

                        }

                        document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML = s;
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);


                    }
            else
            {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road(DRIVING).");
            }
                });



                directionsService.route(request2, function (response, status) {   // RouteService
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        globalResponse = response;
                        routeArr2 = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < globalResponse.routes.length; i++) {

                            routeArr2.push([globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text, globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text]);
                        }
                        var s = document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML;
                        for (i = 0; i < routeArr2.length; ++i) {

                            routeArr2[i][0] = routeArr2[i][0].trim();
                            routeArr2[i][0] = routeArr2[i][0].substring(0, routeArr2[i][0].length - 3)
                            routeArr2[i][1] = routeArr2[i][1].split(' ');
                            if (routeArr2[i][1].length == 2 && routeArr2[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'm') {
                                routeArr2[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr2[i][1][0]);
                            }
                            else if (routeArr2[i][1].length == 4 && routeArr2[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'h') {
                                routeArr2[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr2[i][1][0]) * 60 + parseInt(routeArr2[i][1][2]);
                            }
                            else {
                                routeArr2[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr2[i][1][0]) * 24 * 60 + parseInt(routeArr2[i][1][2] * 60);   //for day hour minutes,all calculation under mins
                            }
                            s += "Distance: " + routeArr2[i][0] + ", " + "Duration: " + routeArr2[i][1] + "<br />";

                        }

                        document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML = s;
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                    }
            else
            {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road(WALKING).");
            }
                });



                directionsService.route(request3, function (response, status) {   // RouteService
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        globalResponse = response;
                        routeArr3 = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < globalResponse.routes.length; i++) {

                            routeArr3.push([globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].distance.text, globalResponse.routes[i].legs[0].duration.text]);
                        }
                        var s = document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML;
                        for (i = 0; i < routeArr3.length; ++i) {

                            routeArr3[i][0] = routeArr3[i][0].trim();
                            routeArr3[i][0] = routeArr3[i][0].substring(0, routeArr3[i][0].length - 3)
                            routeArr3[i][1] = routeArr3[i][1].split(' ');
                            if (routeArr3[i][1].length == 2 && routeArr3[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'm') 
                {
                                routeArr3[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr3[i][1][0]);
                            }
                            else if (routeArr3[i][1].length == 4 && routeArr3[i][1][1].charAt(0) == 'h') 
                {
                                routeArr3[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr3[i][1][0]) * 60 + parseInt(routeArr3[i][1][2]);
                            }
                            else 
                {
                                routeArr3[i][1] = parseInt(routeArr3[i][1][0]) * 24 * 60 + parseInt(routeArr3[i][1][2] * 60);   //for day hour minutes,all calculation under mins
                            }
                            s += "Distance: " + routeArr3[i][0] + ", " + "Duration: " + routeArr3[i][1] + "<br />";

                        }

                        document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML = s;
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                    }
            else
            {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road(TRANSIT).");
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Here's the AJAX request
                    var httpRequest;
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
                        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
            { // IE 6 and older
                        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {                           // here the function name that is designed to handle the response
                        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {          //200 OK response code. // 4 is complete response received
                            alert(httpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    };
                    httpRequest.open("POST", "testdb.php", true);       // here true means asynchronously server is called,i.e,without page reloading
                    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httpRequest.send("&source=" + source + "&destination=" + destination + "&sel=" + sel + "&i=" + i + "&routes=" + JSON.stringify(routeArr) + "&routes2=" + JSON.stringify(routeArr2) + "&routes3=" + JSON.stringify(routeArr3));


                });

             var sel = document.getElementById('modes').value;                  // which mode the user is preferring

            }
        </script>
        <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Source:
                    <input type="text" id="txtSource" style="width: 200px"/>
                    &nbsp; Destination:
                    <input type="text" id="txtDestination" style="width: 200px"/>
                    &nbsp; Travel Mode:
                    <select id="modes">
                        <option value="driving">Driving</option>
                        <option value="transit">Transit</option>
                        <option value="walking" selected>Walking</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()"/>
                    <hr/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div id="dvDistance">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my php file:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['source'], $_POST['destination'], $_POST['sel'], $_POST['i']) && count($_POST['routes']) && count($_POST['routes2']) && count($_POST['routes3']))
    {
        $routes_array = json_decode($_POST['routes'], true);
        $routes_array2 = json_decode($_POST['routes2'], true);
        $routes_array3 = json_decode($_POST['routes3'], true);
        echo "Routes read";


        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");      // Create connection

        if ($conn->connect_error)                                   // Check connection
        {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $i = $_POST['i'];
        $sel = $_POST['sel'];
        $source = $_POST['source'];
        $destination = $_POST['destination'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO trip(source, destination, mode, num_routes) VALUES('{$source}', '{$destination}', '{$sel}', '{$i}')";
        if($conn->query($query))
        {

            $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
            foreach($routes_array as $route)
            {
                $distance = $route[0];
                $duration = $route[1];
                $query = "INSERT INTO droute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
                $conn->query($query);
            }
            echo "Sumeet!!!Success";
        }
            else
            {
            echo "Something went wrong!!! Record couldn't be inserted";
        }
            if($conn->query($query))
        {
            $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
            foreach($routes_array2 as $route2)
            {
                $distance = $route2[0];
                $duration = $route2[1];
                $query = "INSERT INTO wroute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
                $conn->query($query);
            }
            echo "Sumeet!!!Success";
        }
            else
            {
            echo "Something went wrong!!! Record couldn't be inserted";
        }
            if($conn->query($query))
        {
            $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
            foreach($routes_array3 as $route3)
            {
                $distance = $route3[0];
                $duration = $route3[1];
                $query = "INSERT INTO troute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
                $conn->query($query);
            }
            echo "Sumeet!!!Success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Something went wrong!!! Record couldn't be inserted";
        }                              
        $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hey anyone please help me on this question,my only data is getting populated on trip table and Droute table but Troute and Wroute is not getting populated. trip(trip_id,src,dest,no. of routes,modes of travel)  and for Droute,Troute and Wroute the table structure is same for all (route_id,trip_id,distance,duration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file, you are executing query thrice, do you really want it that way? It will generate three different insert_id s for the same route.  I guess this is what you want.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['source'], $_POST['destination'], $_POST['sel'], $_POST['i']) && count($_POST['routes']) && count($_POST['routes2']) && count($_POST['routes3']))
{
    $routes_array = json_decode($_POST['routes'], true);
    $routes_array2 = json_decode($_POST['routes2'], true);
    $routes_array3 = json_decode($_POST['routes3'], true);
    echo "Routes read";


    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");      // Create connection

    if ($conn->connect_error)                                   // Check connection
    {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $i = $_POST['i'];
    $sel = $_POST['sel'];
    $source = $_POST['source'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO trip(source, destination, mode, num_routes) VALUES('{$source}', '{$destination}', '{$sel}', '{$i}')";
    if($conn->query($query))
    {
        $route_count = 0;
        $trip_id = $conn->insert_id;
        foreach($routes_array as $route)
        {
            $distance = $route[0];
            $duration = $route[1];
            $query = "INSERT INTO droute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
            $conn->query($query);
            $route_count++;
        }
        echo "Sumeet!!!Success";


        foreach($routes_array2 as $route2)
        {
            $distance = $route2[0];
            $duration = $route2[1];
            $query = "INSERT INTO wroute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
            $conn->query($query);
            $route_count++;
        }
        echo "Sumeet  2 !!!Success";   

        foreach($routes_array3 as $route3)
        {
            $distance = $route3[0];
            $duration = $route3[1];
            $query = "INSERT INTO troute(trip_id, distance, duration) VALUES({$trip_id}, '{$distance}', '{$duration}')";  //distance in km and duration in mins
            $conn->query($query);
            $route_count++;
        }
        echo "Sumeet 3!!!Success";            

    }
        else
        {
        echo "Something went wrong!!! Record couldn't be inserted";
    }


    // insert route count whereever you need to ....

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: but there is still one issue that is num_routes that i am printing is still showing only route_count of my Droute not of others, i mean i am getting total of 10 routes including for driving,walking and transit ,but how can i count for all of them and insert in myroute_count